# Exercise 1.3 in Atiyah and Mcdonald?

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra

$A$ is a commutative ring with 1.

Exercise 1.3 of Atiyah and Mcdonald's commutative algebra is to generalize exercise 1.2 to polynomial ring $A[x_1,...,x_n]$. Exercise 1.2(iv) says:

> $a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n=f\in A[x]$ is said to be primitive iff $(a_0,...,a_n)=(1)$. Show that $fg\in A[x]$ is primitive iff $f\in A[x]$ and $g\in A[x]$ is primitive.

There is a natural way to define primitivity in $A[x_1,...,x_n]$: $f\in A[x_1,...,x_n]$ is primitive iff coefficients of $f$ generate $A$. I solved this exercise in this setting.

The other "definition" I can figure out is: $f\in A[x_1,...,x_n]$ is primitive iff $\forall i(f\in A[...,\widehat{x_i},...][x_i]$ is primitive)

I have three questions:

1. is it true that

> $\exists i(f\in A[...,\widehat{x_i},...][x_i]$ is primitive) implies $\forall i(f\in A[...,\widehat{x_i},...][x_i]$ is primitive)?

2. is there any connection between two definitions given above?
3. if the above two fails for general situation,is there any kinds of ring for which there is some interesting result?

Thanks.

Comment: The polynomial $xy$ in two variables $x$ and $y$ is primitive for the first definition, but not for the second definition (indeed, as a polynomial in $y$, its only nonzero variable is $x$, which does not generate $1$).

Comment: 1) No. Take $2+3y\in \Bbb Z[x,y]$ where the coefficients when seen as an element of $\Bbb Z[x][y]$ are $2$ and $3$, and thus generate the whole of $\Bbb Z[x]$, while when seen as $\Bbb Z[y][x]$ the polynomial is just the constant term $2+3y$, which doesn't generate all of $\Bbb Z[y]$.

Comment: thank both of you,I now see how trivial this question is......@darij grinberg @Arthur